# MySQL keeps crashing due to bug

Tags: mysql, crash

So about a week ago, I finally figured out what was causing my server to continually crash.

After reviewing my mysqld.log I keep seeing this same error,

```
101210  5:04:32 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
```

Here is a link to the bug report, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35346 someone recommend that you set the max_join_size vaule in my.cnf to 4M, and I did. I assumed this fixed the issue, and it was working for about a week with no issues until today...

I checked MySQL and the same error is now back,

```
101216 06:35:25  mysqld restarted
101216  6:38:15 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
101216  6:38:15 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
101216 06:40:42  mysqld ended
```

Anyone know how I can really fix this issue? I can't keep having mysql crash like this.

EDIT: I forgot to mention every time this happens I get an email from linode staying I have a high disk io rate

Your Linode, has exceeded the notification threshold (1000) for disk io rate by averaging 2483.68 for the last 2 hours.

Comment: Why do you say it crashes?  It looks like mysqld persisted for at least another two minutes after the second example.

Comment: It crashes, I have to restart it or none of my applications can connect to MySQL since it is down.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to do a 4GiB join? Are you taking a full Cartesian product, especially one you didn't intend to? (`SELECT *whatever* from big_table, bigger_table WHERE whatever > 5 /* oops, forgot the join criteria */`)

I suggest logging activity, to try and find the query responsible for the crash. Then you can change the query, and file a bug report w/ MySQL.

Comment: That is the bug right there, and there is already a bug report for it

Comment: The bug you linked generates a warning message, not (AFAICT from the bug log) a server crash. I suspect something else is causing the server death. Did you run out of disk space or memory, for example? Performing a huge join could cause that.

Answer (score 0):

I think defining max_join_size to 4294967295 in your MySQL database before **scripts/mysql_install_db.sh** will run:

**scripts/mysql_system_tables.sql**

**scripts/fill_help_tables.sql**

may fix the warning.